# problem on understanding the theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

**Theorem** Let $R,R'$ be a two rings, let $\phi:R\to R'$ be a ring homomorphism,
Given an element $\alpha\in R'$, there is a unique ring homomorphism $\Phi:R[x]\to R'$ which agrees with the map $\phi$ on constant polynomial and sends $x\mapsto \alpha$.

I didn't understand the way map $\Phi$ defined.
If I'll get the map then I can try to prove this theorem.
Help me to understand the map $\Phi$.

Thanks!

Comment: $\Phi (a_0+a_1x)=\Phi(a_0)+\Phi(a_1x)=\Phi(a_0)+\Phi(a_1)\Phi(x)=\phi(a_0)+\phi(a_1)\alpha$ ...

Comment: Are you sure $\alpha\in R$?

Comment: I am sorry, I edited.

Comment: Think of it as evaluation, It maps $x $ to $\alpha$ and the 'constants' from $a $ to $\phi(a)$.

Comment: let $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n r_ix^i$ be  a polynomial in $R[x]$, then $\Phi(f(x))=\Phi(\sum_{i=1}^n r_ix^i)=\Phi(\sum_{i=1}^n r_i)\Phi(\sum_{i=1}^nx^i)=\sum_{i=1}^n\phi(r_i)\sum_{i=1}^n\Phi(x^i)=\sum_{i=1}^nr_i'\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha^i=\sum_{i=1}^nr_i'\alpha^i$. 

Am i getting the map correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick note: all rings in your question and this answer are commutative (or else the theorem statement is incorrect).

---

We want to produce a homomorphism $\Phi : R[x] \to R'$ such that $\Phi|_R = \phi$ and $\Phi(x) = \alpha$. An arbitrary element of $R[x]$ is a polynomial of the form $$\sum_{i=0}^n c_i x^i$$ for some $c_0, \dots, c_n \in R$. Where should this element be sent by $\Phi$? Well, $\Phi$ is supposed to be a ring homomorphism, so we should have

$$\Phi\left(\sum_{i=0}^n c_i x^i\right) = \sum_{i=0}^n \Phi(c_i x^i) = \sum_{i=0}^n \Phi(c_i) \Phi(x^i) = \sum_{i=0}^n \Phi(c_i) \Phi(x)^i$$

We're also supposed to have $\Phi(c_i) = \phi(c_i)$ and $\Phi(x) = \alpha$, so we must define

$$\Phi\left(\sum_{i=0}^n c_i x^i\right) = \sum_{i=0}^n \phi(c_i) \alpha^i$$

This shows the uniqueness: if there is any homomorphism $R[x] \to R'$ with the desited properties, it must be given by the above formula. Now you just have to show that this function actually is a homomorphism with the desired properties, and you'll get existence!

Comment: Thank you! I got it completely.